# responsive image map works on PC, but not on cellphones

Tags: image, dictionary, responsive

site: https://beststoresupplies.com

The links click ok on PC, but on cellphones,

only the first row works.

In setting the height of the area, it should have been 33.33% as I have 3 rows, but it does not work even on PC.

So I set it at 11% and worked on PC.

But on cellphones, the 2nd and 3rd-row position is just way off.

**Can any expert help here?**

```html
        <div class="image">
    <img src="/image/data/01000/category12.jpg"   
    alt="FixtureDisplays Brand Image" 
    title="FixtureDisplays Brand Image" 
    class="img-responsive"/>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=candy%20bin" title="Candy Bins" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 0%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=donation%20box" title="Donation Boxes" style="position: absolute; left: 25%; top: 0%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=podium" title="Podiums" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 0%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=card%20rack" title="Greeting Card Rack" style="position: absolute; left: 75%; top: 0%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=menu%20board" title="Menu Board" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 11%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=file%20organizer" title="File Organizer" style="position: absolute; left: 25%; top: 11%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=kettle" title="Kettles" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 11%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=phone%20locker" title="Lockers" style="position: absolute; left: 75%; top: 11%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=wire%20rack" title="Wire Rack" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; top: 22%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=mobile%20sink" title="Mobile Sink" style="position: absolute; left: 25%; top: 22%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=hat+rack&page=3" title="Hat Rack" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 22%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?_route_=Showcase_10111&search=10111" title="Showcases" style="position: absolute; left: 75%; top: 22%; width: 25%; height: 11%; z-index: 2;"></ a>
    </div>
```

Comment: try to avoid `position` sometimes will be difficult to maintain... use grid or flex for this

Comment: I added a new answer, that solves your problem! here a gif for see how is works: https://imgur.com/a/59Z0Ap0

Answer (score 0):

**the third edit to this answer:**

explanation below,

this time the code is only in HTML, with also CSS but inside HTML

here how I do it in a video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Oo1.jpg

**change the code to this:**

```html
<!-- COPY only this new 20 lines of html from StackOverFlow - Laaouatni -->
<div style="position: relative;" class="bg-image">
  <!-- your image background -->
  <img style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" src="https://www.beststoresupplies.com/image/data/01000/category12.jpg" alt="FixtureDisplays Brand Image" title="FixtureDisplays Brand Image" class="img-responsive" />

  <!-- for changes, style only the parent element -->
  <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="product-links">
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=candy%20bin" title="Candy Bins"></a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=donation%20box" title="Donation Boxes"></a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=podium" title="Podiums"></a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=card%20rack" title="Greeting Card Rack"></a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=menu%20board" title="Menu Board "></a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=file%20organizer" title="File Organizer "></a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=kettle" title="Kettles "></a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=phone%20locker" title="Lockers"></a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=wire%20rack" title="Wire Rack"></a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=mobile%20sink" title="Mobile Sink"></a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=hat+rack&page=3" title="Hat Rack"></a>
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?_route_=Showcase_10111&search=10111" title="Showcases"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2 edit answer**

gif to see how it works:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjvNC.jpg

explanation below

```css
.bg-image {
  /* DON'T delete this... is important for the .product-links child */
  position: relative;
}

.bg-image img {
  /* responsive image */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.product-links {
  /* grid of 4 items in a columns, automatic number of rows*/
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  /* the links now are above the background (image) */
  /* don't change: if you want to change... before using absolute, you need to set the parent to position:relative */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* the parent of links, set dimensions 100% width and height 100% (100% of the parent so the image, not the all screen) */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- this is the parent, that in css set -->
  <div class="bg-image">

    <!-- this is your src link of background-image -->
    <img src="https://www.beststoresupplies.com/image/data/01000/category12.jpg" alt="FixtureDisplays Brand Image" title="FixtureDisplays Brand Image" class="img-responsive" />

    <!-- links -->
    <!-- if you want to make changed with grid, change the parent css for change all elements inside -->
    <div class="product-links">
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=candy%20bin" title="Candy Bins"></a>
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=donation%20box" title="Donation Boxes"></a>
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=podium" title="Podiums"></a>
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=card%20rack" title="Greeting Card Rack"></a>
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=menu%20board" title="Menu Board "></a>
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=file%20organizer" title="File Organizer "></a>
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=kettle" title="Kettles "></a>
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=phone%20locker" title="Lockers"></a>
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=wire%20rack" title="Wire Rack"></a>
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=mobile%20sink" title="Mobile Sink"></a>
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=hat+rack&page=3" title="Hat Rack"></a>
      <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?_route_=Showcase_10111&search=10111" title="Showcases"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**previous answer**

so don't use `position` because is hard to maintain for responsive layouts...

you can use [CSS GRID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) or [CSS FLEXBOX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)

so with `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);` you will have always 4 items in a column,

if there are more than 4, CSS GRID will automatically create for you more rows.

I see on your website you have done responsive images, so good! `width: 100%; height: auto;`

The HTML seems to have some problems because you have a parent called `.image` but only one element is an image...

the other elements are `<a>` links, but when I see your website seems to be working fine (I don't know if you are using a CMS for this)
however, I changed the HTML to have a `<img>` nested in `<a>`

try to run the code snippet, and tell me if is what you need.

> this is only a beta, you need to change the `src` with your link address of images.

> this is only a beta of the code, don't copy and paste directly on the production site...
>  try to see the code and change where needed to.

**here the demo code:**

```css
.image {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 1rem;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image">
    <!-- 1 -->
    <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="FixtureDisplays Brand Image" title="FixtureDisplays Brand Image" class="img-responsive" />
    <!-- 2 -->
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=candy%20bin" title="Candy Bins">
      <!-- change the src of image to your link -->
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
    </a>
    <!-- 3 -->
    <a href=" https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=donation%20box" title="Donation Boxes">
      <!-- change the src of image to your link -->
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
    </a>
    <!-- 4 -->
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=podium" title="Podiums">
      <!-- change the src of image to your link -->
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
    </a>
    <!-- 5 -->
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=card%20rack" title="Greeting Card Rack">
      <!-- change the src of image to your link -->
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
    </a>
    <!-- 6 -->
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=menu%20board" title="Menu Board">
      <!-- change the src of image to your link -->
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
    </a>
    <!-- 7 -->
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=file%20organizer" title="File Organizer">
      <!-- change the src of image to your link -->
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
    </a>
    <!-- 8 -->
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=kettle" title="Kettles">
      <!-- change the src of image to your link -->
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
    </a>
    <!-- 9 -->
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=phone%20locker" title="Lockers">
      <!-- change the src of image to your link -->
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
    </a>
    <!-- 10 -->
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=wire%20rack" title="Wire Rack">
      <!-- change the src of image to your link -->
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
    </a>
    <!-- 11 -->
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=mobile%20sink" title="Mobile Sink">
      <!-- change the src of image to your link -->
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
    </a>
    <!-- 13 -->
    <a href="https://www.fixturedisplays.com/index.php?route=product/search&search=hat+rack&page=3" title=" Hat Rack ">
      <!-- change the src of image to your link -->
      <img src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/87947051?v=4" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```